# What is a good way to fake a callback context if a callback function doesn't have such a parameter?

Tags: c++, callback

Usually callback functions should have a "context" argument which can be used for an object pointer, but what is a good way to fake this for legacy code where there is no such argument?

I often need to write code which calls into a library and receives callback calls from it, however the callback must actually run in the context of my object.

I usually fake this by using a static function as a callback, which in turn contains a static variable which I set to the object pointer on which it then calls a member function. This is my callback for Microsoft's FMIFS library:

```
// Return TRUE for Continue, FALSE for Cancel
/* static */ BOOLEAN CALLBACK CFmifsCallbackHelper::FmifsCallback
(
    zFmifsCallbackCommand Command, 
    DWORD                 Modifier, 
    PVOID                 Argument
)
{
    static CFmifsCallbackHelper* helper = NULL;

    if (Command == zFmifsCallbackCommandInvalid)
    {
        helper = reinterpret_cast<CFmifsCallbackHelper*>(Argument);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else if (helper)
    {
        BOOLEAN retValue = helper->Callback(Command, Modifier, Argument);
        return retValue;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

So the static callback function needs to be called once with a "misused" parameter before it is actually used as a callback, it only works if the parameter is at least pointer-sized, and there can be no concurrent calls for different contexts. Also, I need to be absolutely sure that the library will never use the `Command` value (`zFmifsCallbackCommandInvalid`) which I use to set the context (`helper`). Pretty bad all in all. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Why don't you just pass in the context into the callback function?

Comment: The context needs to be passed in by the libary, but isn't. The parameter `Argument` is not intended for that use, and is used by the library for other data. (And the library functions e.g. `Format` and `Chkdsk` also don't take a context parameter).

Comment: Is there something you could do with thread local storage?  i.e. have an array of context using the current thread as an index (hash-key), then your callback could lookup the context using the current thread.  make sure the thread/context is cleared when then callback work is completed.

Comment: If I understood your code correctly you use `Argument` to calculate `helper`. If argument is "not enough sized" then you can use static map `Argument`=>`CFmifsCallbackHelper*`. Also, I didn't understand why _"function needs to be called once with a "misused" parameter"_ Isn't it possible to "lazy" initialize pointer to object during an actual call?

Comment: You may want to spend some time reviewing the Library's Documentation/Tutorials. It seems really odd that they would explicitly provide a `PVOID` argument (which I'm assuming is an alias for `void *`) and then make it inaccessible/inconvenient for you.

Comment: @Xirema it's not inaccessible, it contains information related to the callback status (which can be different `struct`s, hence the `void*` type).

Comment: @FelixDombek My argument remains: You should find out *exactly* what struct(s) gets passed in for your specific callback handler, and whether "User Data" (usually in the form of another `void *`) can be passed to that(/those) type(s) or not.

Comment: @Xirema unfortunately it can't: the structs aren't even passed for all calls, sometimes `Argument` is NULL. At other times, it can point to a single string or a long. There is no user data that can be set.

Comment: How many callbacks do you need?  How many of a given signature?  How many of a given lambda type?  How about at once?  What manages the lifetime of the data you need in the callback?  Are you in a context where executable binary size is at a premium, or is the executing platform at least smartphone strength?  (Answer with actual constraints and "wouldn't mind" constraints, and all questions please).

Comment: @Yakk In this use case: A single callback function with a given signature, it must be a `stdcall` callable function, the data I need in the callback is actually a COM object which calls e.g. `FormatEx` in the library fmifs.dll and uses the callback to trigger COM events. My `CFmifsCallbackHelper` class in the example basically just forwards the call to specific member functions of the COM object. There is no constraint other than that, the executing platform is at least XP.

Comment: @fekiz with the descrivbed constraints, use a global variable.  Done.

Comment: @Yakk I had hoped for a more scalable and general solution ...

Comment: @FelixDombek It scales and is more general than your "use static local varaible we set in a fake call to the function" approach.  If you want *less* general, I could say "compile the function, get its address, mark the page as writable, modify the value of the static variable stored in it, mark the page as read only and executable" which I have seen actually used in the past.  But really, if you have global state, you have global state.